# Gitlab-runner in docker - How to run as non root

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, fastlane

I am trying to automate ios build and deployment using fastlane and gitlab ci. My gitlab-runner installed in a docker container. Since runner in docker container runs as root (sudo), pod install gets failed as it does not allow to execute as root user. Anyone faced similar problem? I have tried searching in stackoverflow without success.

```
$ bundle exec pod install
 bundler: failed to load command: pod (/builds/root/fastlaneexample/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/pod) CLAide::Help: [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.
```